# Does anyone know where I can find this sort of l-screw hollow wall anchor combo?

Tags: anchor

I have tried putting a heavy painting up that has two slots where l-shaped screws hold it up. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a drywall anchor long enough so that the l-screws go in deep enough. The only l-shaped screws I can find that are large have too much space between where the screw ridges end and the l-bend starts. I have found an image of the type of hardware I think would work, but can't seem to find it in the U.S. Does anyone know where to find this (see image), or something like it?

[image]

Comment: A decent hardware or diy store.

Comment: Use the term molly bolt, that is what the trades call these anchors but I have never seen one with the bent shaft before.

Comment: While there's nothing inherently wrong with the question, shopping advice tends to get very quickly outdated and, therefore, shopping questions are off-topic here. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see what you can ask about and what not.

Comment: Use hollow wall anchors with screw that normally come with them to set the anchor in the drywall, remove the screw,  then screw in an eye hook that will fit the much shorter depth of the anchor once it is properly compressed.

Comment: You should change the question from a shopping one to a how to hang a heavy item one so it will not be closed.  I have provided an answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Limo is correct, you can replace the machine bolt with an L bolt/hook that has the proper threads.

I prefer [Toggler anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831) for superior weight holding ability. (*Limos advice would work for those as well.*)

BUT,  positioning both hooks level and **spaced precisely** for the keyhole hangers is a challenge.

If the back of the painting will allow it then i would use  the [French cleat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_cleat) method. If i do not construct one myself from wood then i  use the [Hangman Picture Hanging system](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-18-in-Hangman-Picture-Hanging-System/3058195).

It may bridge two studs or at least one, and the picture can slide side to side somewhat if you need.

Comment: Forgot about French cleats.....best way to hang something big and heavy!